# Rails - Is keeping parameters in action better than using before_action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I finished 'Rails Best Practice' Level 1 course of Code School, it introduced a Best Practice that instance variable shouldn't be hidden.

So instead of using before_action, keeping parameters in action is better, like following:

```
def edit
  @tweet = get_tweet(params[:id])
end

def update
  @tweet = get_tweet(params[:id])
end

private
def get_tweet(tweet_id)
  Tweet.find(tweet_id)
end
```

Could anyone explain why it better than using before_action ? I can't exactly understand.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you show the snippet of code exactly as you would do it with `before_action`. Not quite sure I understand the dilemma.

Comment: Can you send me one pdf copy of the book *Ruby Science* ? email id is mentioned in my profile.

Answer (score 2):

The idea being expressed seems to be increase instance variable visibility, so that people don't forget there are some with specific names floating around. These can play an important part as your project grows and you end up using multiple/nested/partial views because variable names may start clashing.

But a better mechanism is to do away with instance variables entirely and use local variables instead. That way:

- You will need to pass them explicitly to a view so you really know they are needed
- Localise their effect and prevent clashes
- Make the view self-documenting for people who manage it later

Refer:

- http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/27-replace-instance-variable-with-local-variable
- http://thepugautomatic.com/2013/05/locals/

Answer (score 1):

I just watched the video, what he, Gregg, is doing:`refactoring` and by making `get_tweet private` It allows you to share common code between controllers and furthermore prevents Rails from ever making it available as a public action on your controller. But it is natural to use `before_filter` filter on action when dealing with `Authorization`, `Logging`, and `Wizard`. I hope this helps!!